# app.get isn't called in Heroku but works in local machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have made an email verification using jwt token, the problem is the route is working on my local machine when I clicked on the email link it successfully redirects me to login page, however when I try to push it in Heroku, it does not work. This route isn't called when I click on the email verification link. Im guessing it has the problem in reactjs and heroku. but all of my other routes are working except with this one.

server.js

```
app.get("/confirmation/:token", (req, res) => {
  //console.log(req.params.token);

  // Just for example:
  const PROTOCOL = keys.protocol;
  const HOST = keys.host;

  jwt.verify(req.params.token, keys.secretOrKey, function(err, decoded) {
    console.log("myconsole log"); // bar
    User.findOne({ email: decoded.email }, (err, config) => {
      console.log(config.approveReg);
      config.approveReg = true;
      config.save(err => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // res.json({ data: config });
      });
      //  config.approveReg = true;
    });
  });

  return res.redirect(PROTOCOL + keys.dev);
});
```

Component.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/confirmation/" + this.props.match.params.token, {})
      .then(function(response) {
         // window.location("/login");
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

import "./App.css";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import Header from "./components/layout/Header";
import Register from "./components/auth/Register";
import LoginAuth from "./components/auth/LoginAuth";
import Login from "./components/auth/Login";
import Confirmation from "./components/auth/Confirmation";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/loginauth" component={LoginAuth} />
            <Route exact path="/confirmation/:token" component={Confirmation} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you mentioned `reactjs`, so try to show reactjs code also where you make get call at `/confirmation/:token`

Comment: this one, its in my Confirmation component
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/confirmation/" + this.props.match.params.token, {})
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

Comment: @Revansiddh have added my ReactJS, i show it now

Comment: if it is working well in local and have an error in Heroku then check with `api url` is correct whether it is reachable or not

Comment: What happens when you run it in `heroku local web`? Unless you publish your React app at root, you'll need to serve it using express in heroku. Do you get any error when you do `heroku logs`?

Comment: Hi Tan Kim Loong, no I don't have any errors, it just does not read the app.get() when on heroku. I have this code in server if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
} 
does this affect the route?